# simple predicate DSL

Tags: .net, dynamic

In one part of a .NET program I am writing I'd like a user to be able to script a simple function body at runtime that returns true or false only. The user would need the usual basic logical operators, the ability to nest logical operations  (a && (b || c)), and a small set of operators "==" "!=" "contains" "notcontains". In other words I am letting the user write a function that is the predicate of a filter at runtime.

I realise something like IronPython easily fits the bill however there are plenty of other (dangerous) things they could do that I dont want them to be able to.

What would people recommend I use for something like this?

Comment: is it possible for a user to enter a LINQ expression and then dynamically parse this to ensure it is a boolean expression?

Answer (score 0):

If your grammar really is simple, I recommend looking into writing your own parser and a small bytecode interpreter. The development cost isn't as high as you would think, and there are several helpful tools.

Coco/R is a parser-generator that can take a language grammar and produce a parser and scanner for you, that should get you started with a simple interpreter: http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/coco/

There is a sample parser and interpreter called Taste that can help you get started.